# Problems serving a dash webapp in an internal network?

Tags: flask, plotly-dash

I have the following problem:

I'm trying to serve a dash app in my internal network.

```
from dash import Dash, html

app = Dash(__name__)
app.layout = hmtl.Div([html.H1('hello dash'), html.Div('test')])

app.run_server(host='0.0.0.0', port=8050, debug=False)
```

The above doesn't work - meaning I can only access it from the host machine when navigating to the browser. Other computers on the local network get an error saying:

[image: αό]

Network admin couldn't see that there were any issues so I wrote a similar min server but running on flask to see if the issue was Dash and indeed the following is reachable just fine from a different machine on the network:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'asdf'

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8050)
```

And indeed this works just fine. Any idea what might be going on?

I saw this comment here which seemed to indicate someone experienced some issues due to browser settings?
[Error while running Dash app locally, "This site can’t be reached"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64774601/error-while-running-dash-app-locally-this-site-can-t-be-reached/64779181?noredirect=1#comment127492272_64779181)

I was trying to access this using chrome

Comment: That doesn't look like an internal IP address, that looks more like a public one. Try using the internal IP address for the machine hosting the app.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is the internal one, also why would flask work and dash not work. If what you suggest were correct I would assume neither to work